# How to store a variable for the config file in i3wm?

Tags: display, brightness, xrandr, i3-wm

I'm trying out i3wm and I've got the hang of it so far. I like it but my main issue is xbrightness, which I can't seem to figure out. I've tried the configuration and never got it to work even though it has my display folder. :/

To set the brightness I use `xrandr --output eDP --brightness x` where `x` is a number between 0 and 1. I actually like this solution a lot and I set it up with my keybindings in i3wm. I can make it so when I press the <kbd>Brightness +/-</kbd> button it makes it a certain brightness, but I can't figure out how to store the current value.

AFAIK I can't do like +0.1 - it has to be a hard-coded value. If I could store a value somewhere of the current brightness and just add/subtract 0.1 each time that would be perfect, but I'm not sure how to do that since it's just a config file and not like a bash script that I'm using to run commands.

How can I accomplish this?

Currently my command is
`bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xrandr --output eDP --brightness 1`

Comment: How can you make it "a certain brightness" if the intent is to increase or decrease the brightness? I don't understand your issue well, I am afraid. Or do you just want to set a fixed brightness with this key? Be aware that you can always call a shell script instead, that can do more trickery if needed than in a single command of a keybinding.

Comment: You can create a bash script and bind a key in i3 config file to run it. The bash script can use environment variable to store current brightness value.